# Extract integers from file hidden between random characters

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct values {
    int a,b,c,d;
};

int main() {
    std::ifstream myfile("myfile.txt");
    std::vector<values> vect;

    // Format of text file is:
    // sdasjkdh234sldaksdj23asd125as24dfs
    // asdac5234sdf435ljk...35wsd63jj
    // asdad234sdf35gg567dfg554ddd


}
```

I need to create a vector from a file where each line contains four integers hidden between random characters, and put them into a vector of structs where each integer is mapped to the four fields in the struct values. The file has no whitespaces.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Read file line by line and match integers with regular expression.

Comment: Replace any non numerical character with a space and use `std::istream::operator<<()` ?

Comment: Read a block of data from the file into memory, the parse the memory. Repeat.

Comment: The **easiest** method is to read one character at a time from the input file.  If the character `isdigit()` then save it, otherwise repeat.  This may not be the most efficient.  Also search stack overflow for "c++ why EOF is bad".

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string line;

while(getline(cin, line))
{
    auto s = std::remove_if(line.begin(), line.end(), [](auto& c) { return !isdigit(c); });
    line.erase(s, line.end());
    vect.push_back(std::stoi(line));
}
```

Comment: care to add some explanation ?

Comment: Isn't there a coding standard rule that says if the code says exactly what it's doing you shouldn't comment them?